# How to execute stored procedure form a flask_sqlalchemy app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a flask app, would like to know, how to call stored procedures in DB by using flask_sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your app starts with something like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy.sql import text as SQLQuery
```

Let's say you have a stored procedure called CustomerStatus_CheckList_sp with integer  parameters

```
parameter1 = 100
parameter2 = 200
querystring = 'EXEC CustomerStatus_CheckList_sp ' + str(parameter1) + ',' +  str(parameter2)
sql = SQLQuery(querystring)
result = db.engine.execute(sql)
rows = []
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

The rows will come back in a format something like this:

```
(1, 'John', 'Smith', 'Area 42')
(2, 'Dr', 'Who', 'Gallifrey')
```

Comment: Almost forgot 
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Comment: How to get result as dict with key ,value .Can you help me ?